I have started learning to create Routes in react but i am struck with a code where various contents of home page are not in a single component
As I stated that I have learned some basics of routing but there always a path defined "/" for home element whereas in my case I have many components of home page that is giving me a headache. I try to wrap them in app.jsx and then use them as home page but at both "http://localhost:5173" and "http://localhost:5173/about/" locations same app.jsx is rendering.
app.jsx
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import HeroSection from "./components/HeroSection";
import FeatureSection from "./components/FeatureSection";
import Workflow from "./components/Workflow";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Pricing from "./components/Pricing";
import Testimonials from "./components/Testimonials";
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto pt-20 px-6">
        <HeroSection />
        <FeatureSection />
        <Workflow />
        <Pricing />
        <Testimonials />
        <Footer />
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;

main.jsx
import React, { Children } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import App from "./App"
import About from './components/About'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: '/about',
        element: <About />,
      }
    ]
  }
])

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
)

I am expecting to create dynamic route as stated

So when you navigate to "/about" you don't see the About component rendered under all the other UI that App renders? What is the issue or problem? Please [edit] to clarify.

No  at "/about" the same UI render of the App.jsx that i have only created for "/" path .

Ok, yes, exactly, because the way you coded it the App component always renders, so it will OFC always render its JSX.

The issue is that you unconditionally render the "home page" content above all nested children route content.
Refactor the code to move the "home page" content into an actual home page component and render it on an index route under App.
Example:
const Home = () => (
  <div className="max-w-7xl mx-auto pt-20 px-6">
    <HeroSection />
    <FeatureSection />
    <Workflow />
    <Pricing />
    <Testimonials />
  </div>
);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Outlet />
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

import App from "./App"
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      { index: true, element: <Home /> }
      { path: '/about', element: <About /> }
    ]
  }
]);

